# Camel route to copy between two s3 buckets fails silently

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am trying to use a camel route copy a file between two s3 buckets and according to the documentation this should be fairly straight forward but the route appears to fail silently.

The object is read from the source bucket and deleted successfully. The test file is only 5K so is not a large. The target bucket is created, if it doesn't already exist but the object is not created in the target bucket. There is no error in the logs.

The java DSL I am using is as follows.

```
from("aws-s3://my-source-bucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client")
.to("aws-s3://my-target-bucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client")
```

When debugging I can see the exchange.getIn().getBody().toString() contains the text file I am testing with.

If I try S3 source to file that is OK and if I try file to S3 target that works OK as well, so I don't believe there is anything incorrect with my endpoint configuration.

I am using a spring boot application with the following mvn dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-aws</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.485</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have now run out of ideas, anyone else got anything?

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: I have never used this component, but according docs, there are some headers shared under same key for both consumer and producer. I could imagine, that problem could be header `CamelAwsS3BucketName` overriding your value `my-target-bucket` (Maybe is file recreated in source bucket?). I would try add `.removeHeaders("CamelAwsS3*")` to route DSL between consumer and producer.

Comment: @Bedla Doing this copies the file but I then get the message `The bucket name must be specified when deleting an object.` So thank you for the input, it seems you are correct.

It looks like I will have to manually set the copy up using a `Processor`. although to me this seems like a bug. I will post the solution here for future reference once I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year since you posted this, so this answer might not be relevant to you. I was having the same problem trying to create an S3 to S3 route but eventually figured it out. Here’s my solution for anyone else having the same problem.

In the Apache Camel S3 component there is a producer operation called copyObject. Just add "&operation=copyObject" to your producer route. The headers needed for this are:

- "CamelAwsS3BucketDestinationName" : The name of the target bucket
- "CamelAwsS3DestinationKey" : Object Key in the target bucket

My Camel Version: 3.0.0-RC3 (Should also work with version 2.24)

```java
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        //URI Paths
        String inDirectory = "aws-s3://my-source-bucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client";
        String outDirectory = "aws-s3://my-target-bucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client";

        //For the copyObject to work you need to specify the name of the destination bucket
        String targetBucket = "my-target-bucket";

        from(inDirectory)
                .process(exchange -> {

                    //set relevant headers, copyObject needs these set to work properly
                    String key = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelAwsS3Key", String.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsS3BucketDestinationName", targetBucket);
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsS3DestinationKey", key); 
                })
                .to(outDirectory + "&operation=copyObject"); 
    }
```

This route also works for copying objects in buckets between AWS accounts. You just have to set the relevant permissions in each account. You can find out how to do that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/).

Relevant Links:

- [Apache Camel S3 Component Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-s3-component.html)
- [If you want to see how camel handles copyObject](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-s3/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws/s3/S3Producer.java) : Line 300

Hope this helps someone! Let me know if you have any questions or better methods!